# Doctor Who episode where people draw on themselves to remember when their memories are erased?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

Title says it all, I can't remember it, it's the episode that's stuck out to me the most.

People draw on themselves to remember when their memories are erased.

Comment: You forgot the things that erase themselves from your memory?  That cra- sorry, I don't remember what I was going to say.

Answer (score 33):

You are probably remembering ["Day of the Moon"](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Day_of_the_Moon_(TV_story)) (2011), where the main characters marked themselves every time they saw a [Silent](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Silent), since they could not remember seeing them, but physical records remained.

Excerpts from the [TARDIS Data Core](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Day_of_the_Moon_(TV_story)):

> Three months after the events of the warehouse, Amy is chased down the
>   Valley of Gods in Utah. **She has strange pen markings all over her skin
>   and arms.** She is cornered between two SUVs and a cliff-face. Canton
>   Everett Delaware III advises her to surrender. When she wonders if he
>   remembers what happened at the warehouse, he responds by shooting her
>   down.

> Canton and Amy head for Graystark Hall, despite it being closed two
>   years ago. They meet Dr Renfrew, who is quite erratic. He leads them
>   inside, explaining that the orphanage will close in 1967. However,
>   Canton corrects him, explaining that it's 1969; Renfrew ignores him
>   slightly and tries to continue removing orders to leave scrawled all
>   over the walls. Amy goes off on her own to investigate, calling the
>   Doctor to inform him they found the place; with Renfrew like he is and
>   the messages on the walls, there is no doubt. The Doctor, in the
>   meantime, has been busy with messing around with the electronics in
>   Apollo 11, adding one of his own devices. After telling Amy that
>   repeated memory wipes can fry one's mind, he hangs up because security
>   has caught him.
>
> Amy continues searching the orphanage, finding a nest of hibernating
>   aliens on the ceiling of a room. **Her nano-recorder flashes red; she
>   has left a message warning herself to leave and there are tally marks
>   all over her arms and face. Eventually, she departs, forgetting,** but
>   one of the aliens wakes as the door slams behind her.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/fun/impossible-astronaut-day

Comment: https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Silence_-_list_of_appearances